# Unit testing $scope.$evalAsync function with Jasmine 2.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test a $scope.$evalAsync function. Here is my code:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function(done) {
    //enable the popover plugin
    done();
    jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    $scope.isKioskIdLoaded.state = true;
});
```

I am having difficult understanding how to get the evalAsync to run in my Jasmine test itself. I am trying to utilize the done() function that is in Jasmine 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$scope.$digest()` to your Jasmine test. You need to trigger a digest after you have added your evalasync function to Angular's asyncQueue.